# Table view data sources running twice, scope issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, scope

I have a UITableView where numberOfSectionsInTableView and numberOfRowsInSection are being called twice, with scope issues on the second run.  If I mask the problem, I get a scope issue on the first run of cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Most data all comes from an NSDictionary which is configured during viewDidLoad.  I also have an NSArray configured at the same time.  Once set they are never changed nor released.

When numberOfSectionsInTableView is called the first time, it's fine.  Counts the elements as needed etc.  It's then immediately called a second time (no idea why).  On the second run, it cannot access the NSDictionary or NSArray items.  Crash even when trying to NSLog them.  For example:

```
NSLog(@"theMainDictionary %@",theMainDictionary);
```

usually results in EXC_BAD_ADDRESS but occasionally something like this:

```
theMainDictionary <_UITableViewSeparatorView: 0x4e73680; frame = (0 307; 320 1); opaque = NO; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x4e4bf20>>
```

Again, this same line runs fine (logging the dictionary as expected) the first run through.

If I mask the problem by returning a fixed NSInteger, numberOfRowsInSection then does the same thing.  If I mask numberOfRowsInSection, cellForRowAtIndexPath crashes on the first run.  Same issue though - can't access theMainDictionary or the related NSArray.

I can't figure out why they're running twice - there's no reloadData anywhere.  Nor do I know why the second call runs any differently.  Any assistance greatly appreciated.

Comment: could you show the code for the entire .m file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably creating your dictionary with `[NSDictionary dictionary]` or one of the several similar factory methods (which returns an autoreleased instance), and then saving it directly to an ivar without retaining it. It will work fine until your program gets back to the main run loop, at which time the autorelease will resolve and the object gets freed.

There are a few ways to fix it:

- Assign to a property declared `retain` rather than an ivar. This means `self.theMainDictionary` rather than just `theMainDictionary`. This will retain it for you, so it will stick around until you release it (or assign a different dictionary or `nil` to the property).
- Use `[[NSDictionary alloc] init]` (or one of the many other init methods) rather than `[NSDictionary dictionary]` style. This returns an instance that you own, so it will stick around until you release it.
- Explicitly call `retain` on the dictionary when saving it to the ivar. This takes ownership, so it will stick around until you release it.

In all cases, do remember to release the dictionary in your `dealloc` method, or the memory will leak.

All of the above probably applies to the array too. See [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH) for a much more detailed explanation of memory management in Cocoa.

Comment: Ugh - can't believe I missed that.  It was originally a property, then changed to an ivar for something else.  Forgetting that step I was looking for the crazy reasons.  Thank you.